# PHP : $this->methodcall() gives error and CalledClass:methodcall() works fine

Tags: php

I am trying to call method `getDetails()` from another class which in turns calls to methods from its own class(i.e, called class) and it does so by

`$this->getAccount()` and `$this->getAddress()` and in called class we have methods like `$this->getAccount()` and `$this->getAddress()` function but when I call

them I get fatal error message as call to undefined method, but when I try calling that method using `CalledClassName::getAddress()` and

`CalledClassName::getAddress()` than it works fine.

My question is that class which am calling(i.e, calledClass ) will always have use `$this->getAddress()` and `$this->getAccount()` as am getting this class

information from other team and there are 3 teams that would be calling functions `getDetails()` which would internally call `getAccount()` and `getAddress()`

functions and so how should I deal with the issue of $this on myside when am calling `getDetails()` function.

Code Example

```
Calling Class:


CalledClass::getDetails() // Call to getDetails function in CalledClass


CalledClass::


public function postalAddress()
{
 return array(
   'addressId' => $address->addressId,
   'city' => $address->city,
   'country' => $address->country,
   'postcode' => $address->postcode,
   'stateOrProvince' => $address->stateOrProvince,
   'street' => $address->streetName,
   'streetNumber' => $address->streetNrFirst,
   'streetSuffix' => $address->streetNrFirstSuffix
  );
};

public function getAddress()
{
 return $this->postalAddress();
}

public function setAccount($account)
{
 $this->account = $account;
}

public function getAccount()
{
 return $this->find('account = 1311143','');
}



 public function getDetails()
    {

     $data = array();
     $data[$address] = $this->getAddress();
     $data[$account] = $this->getAccount();
     return $data;
    }
```

So now using the above method it gives me error and so if am using `CalledClass::getAddress()` and `CalledClass::getAccount()` and it works fine but I cant chang e the code in the calledclass as am calling this function from another team.

Any guidance or suggestions ?

Comment: Your code makes it difficult to find out how you actually define the classes. `CalledClass::getAccount()` means that you are calling a static method of class `CalledClass`. So I guess you didn't define the classes properly. Please provide a more complete class definition.

Comment: Yes. This are all static calls. I have just not used the exact naming of class but logic is same.

Comment: `$this` needs an instance object to work on. ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function you are trying to call from another class is *static*, you need to use the `::` (scope resolution operator) to call on it. It is also the same way when trying to access static properties.

> Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object created, the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared as static.

Taken from [**PHP: Static Keyword**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

In the meantime for your method call to work without having the ability to modify the other member's code is to use `CalledClass::getAddress()`